# Is there a proper name for counting with letters?

Tags: numbers, alphabet

How should one refer to the practice of using letters instead of numbers for counting?

I'm referring to this:

> "A, B, C, ... X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG... ZX, ZY, ZZ, AAA,
>   AAB..."

Microsoft Excel uses this notation for spreadsheet columns, but I'm unaware if there's a proper name for this. *"Alphabetic numbering"* sounds rather nebulous, but it's the closest I can think of.

---

**UPDATE:** Found the name with the help of FumbleFingers' answer; it's called *bijective hexavigesimal* or [bijective base-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems#Bijective_numeration), a type of [bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system):

> In the bijective base-26 system one may use the Latin alphabet letters "A" to "Z" to represent the 26 digit values one to twenty-six.
>
> With this choice of notation, the number sequence (starting from 1) begins A, B, C, ..., X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, ..., AX, AY, AZ, BA, BB, BC, ...
>
> Each digit position represents a power of twenty-six, so for example, the numeral ABC represents the value 1\times 26^2 + 2\times 26^1 + 3\times 26^0.

"Hexavigesimal" itself seems to refer to any numbering system that uses a radix of 26, rather than one that uses strictly alphabetic characters alone. So while it wasn't *quite* correct, it put me on the right path.

Comment: This is a good question.  I'm not sure that there is a name for it.  Counting with letters preceded counting with numbers.  Anciently, whether it be the Greeks, the Hebrews or the Egyptians, peoples' letters were also their numbers.  The Romans were a bit of an aberration because these others used A(α,א,..) for 1, B(β,ב,..) for 2, etc.  It wasn't until the adoption of Arabic numbers that numbers became different than letters.  It often becomes the case that the original form of something, the way it was originally done, has no name, only the innovation, the new way gets a name.

Comment: You should know that "bijective" adjectivally refers to associating two sets in such a way that every member of each set is uniquely paired with a member of the other set.  If one set is numbers and the other set is letters, then that would be *bijective*.  However, *bijective* isn't limited to numbers.  For example, if one set is John, Mary, and George, and another set is red, green, and blue, and you uniquely associate John with red, Mary with green, and George with blue, that is a *bijective* association.  It has nothing to do with numbers but only associating two sets in such a manner.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Aye, but when mentioning "bijective base-", it makes it clear the topic is numerical in nature. The added information is interesting though, thank you. =)

Comment: *Bijective* only describes the assignment.  In mathematics and linguistics, that method would be described as *shortlex* and the use of letters would be called *lexicographcial.*  You can look both of these terms up in any textbook and probably in Wikipedia.  None of these adjectives are a noun, though.  They are not a name for the method, which is what you asked for.

Comment: I really don't see the relevance of ***bijective*** to this context. I'm also somewhat dubious as to the merits of the recent update to the question text.

Comment: It's not a simple matter of saying "base-26 notation", because that doesn't explicitly rule out digits from the numbering system. What I referred to was a system *strictly* using alphabetic characters, whereas hexavigesimal appears to be less specific.

Comment: @Alhadis: You conceptualize wrongly. *Base 26* itself simply means there are 26 "digits" in the counting system. In principle it's irrelevant which set of 26 symbols are used to represent those digits, but in practice it would never occur to anyone to use anything *other* than (uppercase) lettters, since the whole *reason* for using base 26 in the first place is that there are 26 letters in the alphabet.

Comment: Well... no. Base-26 may also pertain to a system that combines both digits and letters. For instance, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP". More pertinently, expressing a number in ECMAScript using a radix of 26 really doesn't give the expected result (`28..toString(26)` -> "12" instead of "AB").

Comment: @Alhadis : So then *Bijective Base-K* isn't the answer you are looking for, for it could be 0-0, 1-1, 2-2...9-9, 10-A, 11-B, etc.  It can include counting 0-9 using numerals instead of letters--according to you.

Comment: From cursory Googling, it seems "bijective base-26" itself is moderately established within programming circles as the name for a specifically-alphabetic numbering system, often used in spreadsheets. So in a programming context, it seems accurate.

Comment: Also, using a radix beyond 10 doesn't necessarily imply the use of letters. It may also involve the use of punctuation or symbols instead (base64-encoded data, for instance, uses a case-sensitive combination of letters, digits, and a few punctuation symbols: `+ / =`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the "pseudo-technical" term is [**hexavigesimal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems#Standard_positional_numeral_systems). But you probably won't find that in a dictionary. Most people just refer to [base 26 Alphabet Numbers](http://www.minus40.info/sky/alphabetcountdec.html)

Comment: Perfect! Googling "hexavigesimal" brought up a [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8603480/), where a user namedropped "Bijective Hexavigesimal", a type of [bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system).

Comment: @Alhadis: Actually, I used to use base **36** a lot in my programming days (it's an easy way to represent large numbers in short form using the common "digit" symbols 0-9, A-Z). But I certainly never used Wikipedia's ***hexatrigesimal*** - all my inline comments referred to the format as ***radix 36***. So although it's true that *most* people just refer to your one as ***base 26***, I personally would have called that ***radix 26*** if I'd had any real need for a term.

Comment: Basically, I [wrote a JavaScript function](https://github.com/Alhadis/Snippets/commit/30cd58e0) to convert a number to its "alphabetically-indexed" counterpart. Trouble is, I had no idea what to name it, and base-26 didn't make it obvious enough that numbers were *not* included in the result. It also made me wonder if there was a more formal description for what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Alhadis: oic. Well, you could have saved yourself the bother by looking at [How to create a function that converts a Number to a Bijective Hexavigesimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603480/), asked on SO several years ago. But at least I can now see where ***bijective*** comes into play - it just means adding 65 to each "digit" to get the ascii code of an upper-case letter for i/o purposes.

Comment: I enjoy challenging myself with writing code from scratch without Googling for answers. This is how archnerds like myself spend their Sunday evenings, heh.